# WPF crash with Intel HD video cards

Tags: wpf

I have a problem with my WPF application using the Intel HD video cards. The application crashes at starting time with a NullReferenceException within the PresentationCore.ni.dll - the system dll. With ATI HD video cards it works without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but this seems to be a driver problem. You can try software rendering to avoid using [hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951058/software-rendering-mode-wpf/4951250#4951250).

Comment: Do I need to disable the hardware rending on every xaml page?

Comment: I did it on every window. This is not so much work as far as we derived our base window from built in window and so there was only one place to add the code.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore. The problem appears only on Intel video cards with HD capabillities

Comment: The problem was two windows services used for Automated Testing.