# Wpf performance borderless window with aero off

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having an issue with a borderless transparent window that works like an overlay for a game. With Aero on, the performance is stable but as soon as I turn off Aero the fps drops from 120 to 30 fps. Read that this has to do with DWM and transparency and that wpf renders in software mode instead of hardware acc.

Is there a way to force the window to be run in hardware mode instead of software no matter if Aero is disabled or enabled?

Thanks.,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Software rendering mode - WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951058/software-rendering-mode-wpf)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, already read that thread.Thats for making it run in Software mode, I want it always to be rendered in hardware or a fix for when aero is turned off.

Comment: So forcing hardware mode doesnt work?

Comment: The only options are Software or Default. When people have Aero off it automatically switches over to Software rendering making it lag like crazy. 

Is there an override or Pinvoke to enable Aero just for my application? Think it has to do with they having transparancy off.