# WPF rendering lines on window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a wpf application that constantly produces odd straight lines (grey) across the screen.
As the mouse moves around they appear and disappear.
Sorry for the bad description but its hard to describe.
I wonder if there is anything I can do about it.

[image: screenshot]

I have tried a few rendering options and so forth.

```
 <dxg:GridControl SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
```

and

```
RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
                RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have similar issues with big black vertical bars.  Only resolved by switching to software only rendering:

```
System.Windows.Media.RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

Comment: Does it have any detriment effects to the application? 
I also used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951058/software-rendering-mode-wpf as help with this.