# GUI elements are only shown when mouse is moved over them

Tags: wpf, user-interface, .net-3.5, controls

in my company we developed a C#/WPF application and everything works fine. By request of our customer we are limited to the .NET 3.5 framework. In the application there is a settings dialog which is displayed correctly on our companies windows 7 systems. Now our customer has sent us a screenshot that shows the dialog (a window) which is totaly blank. He also wrote that the ui controls only appear if he moves the mouse over them.

We are not able to reproduce this. It looks like a missing repaint of the window or something like this. It is working perfectly on several of our systems. Does anyone know what could cause this effect? We do not have any informations about the computer systems that are used, except that they use windows 7.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a hardware render bug.

Try a software render mode(this needs a change in your source code):
[Software rendering mode - WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951058/software-rendering-mode-wpf)

Or just ask client to enable software mode on his machine:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks alot. Our client wrote today that this issue occures only at times. Would this confirm your theory? Or would the problem always occure if it is really a hardware render bug?

Comment: If client does not have the problems with software render, then it is most likely hardware bug(in case of VM hardware realization) or incompatibility.