# Visual Studio WinForm Render Mode

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, controls

Does anyone know is there any opportunity to set render mode for WinForms ?
I mean setting software rendering mode for specific window or whole application, I am looking the same like describing here [Software rendering mode - WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951058/software-rendering-mode-wpf#)
but for WinForms, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software rendering is what WinForms do already, for all windows and controls, using GDI and GDI+, you can get started [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da0f23z7(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you want hardware accelerated graphics, you need to use some graphics library, like OpenGL or DirectX.

WPF uses DirectX modules to render, because of this you have such option.