# WPF controls not showing after windows update

Tags: c#, wpf

After updating windows to version 1803 none of the WPF applications on a laptop (Intel hd 500 GPU) work properly anymore (start with a blank window or don't show the GUI at all). I've made a simple test app that only shows one button and it results in an empty window. If I turn off the hardware rendering (according to [Software rendering mode - WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951058/software-rendering-mode-wpf)), the application works as expected.

I've tried several versions of the GPU driver including the generic MS one, latest one, latest one recommended by the laptop manufacturer, older ones but all with the same result. The recovery point to the previous version is not available anymore. 
The laptop is barely running existing applications so setting the registry not to use the hardware rendering for all the .net applications is not an option due to performance degradation.

Has anyone experienced anything similar, are any other solutions to solving this?

Thanks,
Tomislav

Comment: Meanwhile, I suggest reporting this to Microsoft

Comment: If you cannot even run a new application, there's nothing we can do. Try to reinstall .NET Framework or run some repair.

Comment: I suspect a windows reinstall/refresh would probably solve these issues. You can do a Windows reset without deleting your files, worth giving that a go first.

Answer (score 2):

The issue happens because I'm using the laptop with the lid down (I connect remotely to it). This seems to put the GPU to sleep/power down state which messes up the applications that use GPU acceleration. Interestingly desktop and some applications run normally. 
Adding a fake display solved the issue (https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/Working-with-closed-lid/td-p/1623610, https://superuser.com/questions/1271344/fake-montitor-for-teamviewer-on-laptop-with-closed-lid).

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this issue and have found that if you uninstall and delete the Intel Display Adapter, then let Windows automatically find the default, this issue is resolved.