# WPF ARM64 app crashes on startup, unless assemblies are forcibly loaded

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, arm64

I have been getting `BadImageException`'s when loading my WPF app exported as arm64 (.NET 6).

These are the publishing settings, but not that it also happens with single file (on/off) and framework-dependant as well.

[image]

[image]

---

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)
System.BadImageFormatException
 at MS.Win32.PresentationCore.UnsafeNativeMethods.MilCoreApi.RenderOptions_ForceSoftwareRenderingModeForProcess(Boolean fForce)
 at System.Windows.Media.RenderOptions.set_ProcessRenderMode(RenderMode value)
 at Myapp.App.App_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) in App.xaml.cs:line 156
 at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
 at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
 at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

The line that triggers the issue looks like this:

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = UserSettings.All.DisableHardwareAcceleration ? RenderMode.SoftwareOnly : RenderMode.Default;
```

Removing that line just makes the app crash in the next line (a `FindResource()` call).

---

At first, I thought it could be related to some of my projects (or dependencies, such as SharpDX) being exported as x86 and failing to load.

So, I decided to export as self-contained + not as single file, to be able to scan all assemblies.
I simply add a method to execute a for loop before the app passed though the line that triggered the crash, calling `AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(name)` for all assemblies in the same folder.

By doing that, the app worked normally.
What's going on here?

Here are the results of the scan:

```
Accessibility.dll - AnyCPU
clretwrc.dll - Not a valid assembly
clrjit.dll - Not a valid assembly
coreclr.dll - Not a valid assembly
D3DCompiler_47.dll - Not a valid assembly
dbgshim.dll - Not a valid assembly
DirectWriteForwarder.dll - None
hostfxr.dll - Not a valid assembly
hostpolicy.dll - Not a valid assembly
KGySoft.CoreLibraries.dll - AnyCPU
KGySoft.Drawing.dll - AnyCPU
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll - AnyCPU
Microsoft.CSharp.dll - AnyCPU
Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.arm64.dll - Not a valid assembly
Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll - AnyCPU
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll - AnyCPU
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll - AnyCPU
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Forms.dll - AnyCPU
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Forms.resources.dll - AnyCPU
Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll - AnyCPU
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.AccessControl.dll - AnyCPU
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll - AnyCPU
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll - AnyCPU
mscordaccore.dll - Not a valid assembly
mscordaccore_arm64_arm64_6.0.422.16404.dll - Not a valid assembly
mscordbi.dll - Not a valid assembly
mscorlib.dll - AnyCPU
mscorrc.dll - Not a valid assembly
netstandard.dll - AnyCPU
PenImc_cor3.dll - Not a valid assembly
PresentationCore.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationCore.resources.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework-SystemData.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework-SystemDrawing.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework.Aero.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework.AeroLite.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework.Classic.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework.Luna.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework.resources.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationFramework.Royale.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationNative_cor3.dll - Not a valid assembly
PresentationUI.dll - AnyCPU
PresentationUI.resources.dll - AnyCPU
ReachFramework.dll - AnyCPU
ReachFramework.resources.dll - AnyCPU
MyApp.dll - AnyCPU
MyApp.Domain.dll - AnyCPU
MyApp.Native.dll - AnyCPU
MyApp.Util.dll - AnyCPU
MyApp.ViewModel.dll - AnyCPU
SharpDX.Direct3D11.dll - AnyCPU
SharpDX.dll - AnyCPU
SharpDX.DXGI.dll - AnyCPU
sni.dll - Not a valid assembly
System.AppContext.dll - AnyCPU
System.Buffers.dll - AnyCPU
System.CodeDom.dll - AnyCPU
System.Collections.Concurrent.dll - AnyCPU
System.Collections.dll - AnyCPU
System.Collections.Immutable.dll - AnyCPU
System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll - AnyCPU
System.Collections.Specialized.dll - AnyCPU
System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll - AnyCPU
System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll - AnyCPU
System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration.dll - AnyCPU
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll - AnyCPU
System.ComponentModel.dll - AnyCPU
System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll - AnyCPU
System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll - AnyCPU
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll - AnyCPU
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll - AnyCPU
System.Configuration.dll - AnyCPU
System.Console.dll - AnyCPU
System.Core.dll - AnyCPU
System.Data.Common.dll - AnyCPU
System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll - AnyCPU
System.Data.dll - AnyCPU
System.Data.Odbc.dll - AnyCPU
System.Data.OleDb.dll - AnyCPU
System.Data.SqlClient.dll - AnyCPU
System.Design.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.Messages.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.Process.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll - AnyCPU
System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll - AnyCPU
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll - AnyCPU
System.DirectoryServices.dll - AnyCPU
System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.dll - AnyCPU
System.dll - AnyCPU
System.Drawing.Common.dll - AnyCPU
System.Drawing.Design.dll - AnyCPU
System.Drawing.dll - AnyCPU
System.Drawing.Primitives.dll - AnyCPU
System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll - AnyCPU
System.Formats.Asn1.dll - AnyCPU
System.Globalization.Calendars.dll - AnyCPU
System.Globalization.dll - AnyCPU
System.Globalization.Extensions.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.Compression.Brotli.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.Compression.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.Compression.Native.dll - Not a valid assembly
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.FileSystem.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.Packaging.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.Pipes.AccessControl.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.Pipes.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.Ports.dll - AnyCPU
System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll - AnyCPU
System.Linq.dll - AnyCPU
System.Linq.Expressions.dll - AnyCPU
System.Linq.Parallel.dll - AnyCPU
System.Linq.Queryable.dll - AnyCPU
System.Management.dll - AnyCPU
System.Memory.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.Http.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.Http.Json.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.HttpListener.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.Mail.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.NameResolution.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.Ping.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.Primitives.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.Quic.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.Requests.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.Security.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.ServicePoint.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.Sockets.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.WebClient.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.WebProxy.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll - AnyCPU
System.Net.WebSockets.dll - AnyCPU
System.Numerics.dll - AnyCPU
System.Numerics.Vectors.dll - AnyCPU
System.ObjectModel.dll - AnyCPU
System.Printing.dll - None
System.Private.CoreLib.dll - AnyCPU
System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll - AnyCPU
System.Private.ServiceModel.dll - AnyCPU
System.Private.ServiceModel.resources.dll - AnyCPU
System.Private.Uri.dll - AnyCPU
System.Private.Xml.dll - AnyCPU
System.Private.Xml.Linq.dll - AnyCPU
System.Reflection.Context.dll - AnyCPU
System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll - AnyCPU
System.Reflection.dll - AnyCPU
System.Reflection.Emit.dll - AnyCPU
System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll - AnyCPU
System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll - AnyCPU
System.Reflection.Extensions.dll - AnyCPU
System.Reflection.Metadata.dll - AnyCPU
System.Reflection.Primitives.dll - AnyCPU
System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll - AnyCPU
System.Resources.Extensions.dll - AnyCPU
System.Resources.Reader.dll - AnyCPU
System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll - AnyCPU
System.Resources.Writer.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.Caching.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.Extensions.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.Handles.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.Loader.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.Numerics.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll - AnyCPU
System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.AccessControl.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Claims.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Permissions.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Principal.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll - AnyCPU
System.Security.SecureString.dll - AnyCPU
System.ServiceModel.dll - AnyCPU
System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll - AnyCPU
System.ServiceModel.Http.dll - AnyCPU
System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll - AnyCPU
System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll - AnyCPU
System.ServiceModel.Security.dll - AnyCPU
System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll - AnyCPU
System.ServiceModel.Web.dll - AnyCPU
System.ServiceProcess.dll - AnyCPU
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll - AnyCPU
System.Speech.dll - AnyCPU
System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll - AnyCPU
System.Text.Encoding.dll - AnyCPU
System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll - AnyCPU
System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll - AnyCPU
System.Text.Json.dll - AnyCPU
System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll - AnyCPU
System.Threading.AccessControl.dll - AnyCPU
System.Threading.Channels.dll - AnyCPU
System.Threading.dll - AnyCPU
System.Threading.Overlapped.dll - AnyCPU
System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll - AnyCPU
System.Threading.Tasks.dll - AnyCPU
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll - AnyCPU
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll - AnyCPU
System.Threading.Thread.dll - AnyCPU
System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll - AnyCPU
System.Threading.Timer.dll - AnyCPU
System.Transactions.dll - AnyCPU
System.Transactions.Local.dll - AnyCPU
System.ValueTuple.dll - AnyCPU
System.Web.dll - AnyCPU
System.Web.HttpUtility.dll - AnyCPU
System.Web.Services.Description.dll - AnyCPU
System.Web.Services.Description.resources.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.resources.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Extensions.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Forms.Design.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Forms.Design.Editors.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Forms.Design.resources.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Forms.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Forms.Primitives.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Forms.Primitives.resources.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Input.Manipulations.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Input.Manipulations.resources.dll - AnyCPU
System.Windows.Presentation.dll - AnyCPU
System.Xaml.dll - AnyCPU
System.Xaml.resources.dll - AnyCPU
System.Xml.dll - AnyCPU
System.Xml.Linq.dll - AnyCPU
System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll - AnyCPU
System.Xml.Serialization.dll - AnyCPU
System.Xml.XDocument.dll - AnyCPU
System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll - AnyCPU
System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll - AnyCPU
System.Xml.XPath.dll - AnyCPU
System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll - AnyCPU
UIAutomationClient.dll - AnyCPU
UIAutomationClient.resources.dll - AnyCPU
UIAutomationClientSideProviders.dll - AnyCPU
UIAutomationClientSideProviders.resources.dll - AnyCPU
UIAutomationProvider.dll - AnyCPU
UIAutomationProvider.resources.dll - AnyCPU
UIAutomationTypes.dll - AnyCPU
UIAutomationTypes.resources.dll - AnyCPU
vcruntime140_cor3.dll - Not a valid assembly
WindowsBase.dll - AnyCPU
WindowsBase.resources.dll - AnyCPU
WindowsFormsIntegration.dll - AnyCPU
WindowsFormsIntegration.resources.dll - AnyCPU
wpfgfx_cor3.dll - Not a valid assembly
```

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951058/software-rendering-mode-wpf

Comment: Doesn't look like so. I'm talking about a `BadImageException`, that is also triggered if the line in question is removed. :)

Comment: Have you tried Platform:  "Any CPU"?

Comment: I'm using .NET 6.

Comment: Have you heard of Fuslogvw.exe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer

Comment: Your list of assemblies seems to contain a bunch of x64 native libraries, which will obviously not run on ARM. I wouldn't be surprised if WPF was not (yet) working on Windows for ARM. I'm assuming you are trying to run this on Arm64/Windows, are you?

Comment: I had forgotten about fuslogvw. Thanks @JeremyThompson, I just have to manage to run it in a client machine, without VS.

Comment: @PMF Yeah, but what it makes no sense is that if I pass all DLLs in `GetAssemblyName()`, the app runs normally. I need to escalate this issue with the .NET team.

Comment: I published with .NET 7 and the app runs normally.