# WPF controls hosted on Winforms application stop updating

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have a legacy Winform application (quite large and monolithic) where we now host WPF controls for the newer functionality.

After some interaction and updating, I get it into a state were all the WPF controls (only) stop updating. Ie if I set a property in the bound view model, the UI does not update. Also controls such as splitters and sliders do not work. Event if I invoke a WPF dialog, the radio button on it does not work.

All the Winforms controls work fine. It is although there is some WPF layer that has stopped functioning.

I have checked everything I can think of, ie everything occurring on correct threads, rendering in SoftwareOnly etc. Pausing the application, I see no locked threads, or anything else suspicious. I don't see any exceptions.

I am now at a loss on how to diagnose what is wrong here.

How can I diagnose such an issue? Ie is there anything common like this that can occur with WPF on Winforms? I have never come across this before!

### Update

I just noticed, if I resize the WPF Winforms parent container, THEN the WPF control updates.

Comment: Do these threads help? [link1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/75df797a-da71-4cf6-af56-9ca98720dc9a/wpf-control-not-painting-properly-?forum=wpf) or [link2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8a5eebc-3d9e-44bb-abe3-8ce0d4e48263/elementhost-aero-glass-rendering-problem-description-and-fix?forum=wpf) or [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470846/winforms-wpf-interop-wpf-content-fails-to-paint)

Comment: @JulianPeffer - thanks having a look (as mentioned in some of them, the app does switch to SoftwareOnly rendering) . I have also since started a MS support case to try and help.